# How to organize the highlighting of a 3D object with which contact occurs?

Tags: unity, 3d

I want to repeat a certain "Select (); - Deselect ();", as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Prompt with advice how to implement it or what you need to read to implement this feature.

I tried to found something similar to what I want to do.

**PlayerInteraction.cs** from [Farm Alarm game](https://brackeysgames.itch.io/farm-alarm) by Brackeys

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (target != col.gameObject && target != null)
        {
            Deselect();
        }

        target = col.gameObject;

        SeedBarrel barrel = target.GetComponent<SeedBarrel>();
        if (barrel != null)
        {
            barrel.Select();
        }

        SpriteRenderer[] srs = target.GetComponentsInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();
        foreach (SpriteRenderer sr in srs)
        {
            sr.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.9f);
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject == target)
        {
            Deselect();
            target = null;
        }
    }

    void Deselect()
    {
        SeedBarrel barrel = target.GetComponent<SeedBarrel>();
        if (barrel != null)
        {
            barrel.DeSelect();
        }

        SpriteRenderer[] srs = target.GetComponentsInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();
        foreach (SpriteRenderer sr in srs)
        {
            sr.color = Color.white;
        }
    }

}
```

But if I understand right it's way for 2D.

P.S. Screenshot from the game "Overcooked"

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @DMGregory update ^^^?

Comment: Great! How have you tried adapting this code for 3D?